# Regex for multiple open-ended phrases in a string using preg_match_all()

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a long string which I'd like to parse for one or more matches.

Each match will start with a name "John" or "Julie", have some text before a second match "brown" or "red", and then remaining text after that matches, before a period OR an additional instance of a match is reached.

For example, this string:

`John likes brown cows and Julie eats red apples and tomatoes. I KNOW John hates red dates that are bruised but John likes red.`

Will yield these 4 matches

```
John likes brown cows and

Julie eats red apples and tomatoes.

John hates red dates that are bruised but

John likes red.
```

I've tried something like this and it's too greedy. The first match matches everything.

`(John|Julie).*?(brown|red).*[.]+`

What do I need to use for preg_match_all() in PHP?

Do I need to use lookahead / lookbehind?

Comment: Use a non-greedy `.*?[.]`

Comment: Use a negative lookahead to prevent going past the next `John|Julie`

Comment: You might use https://regex101.com/r/EcYJPY/1

Comment: Did that pattern work out?